# Using express-validator to check if input is a username or email

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I am trying to validate a login request where it accepts a username that can either be a email or username, and a password. How can I do this with Express-Validator?

I'm reading the documentation and the way the validator works is that you have to pass in the data as the second argument. 
I'm not sure how that's done with checking to see if it's also a username or password.

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const { nickname, password } = req.body;
    // Create a new object based on email or username
    const login = {};
    if (nickname.indexOf('@') === -1) {
        login.nickname = nickname;
    } else {
        login.email = nickname;
    }
    login.password = password;
    // JWT Sign...
});
```

With the validator, I'd also like to check if it's

- A username or email
- If it's a email, make sure it's an actual email using isEmail() validator
- If it's a username, make sure it's more then three characters and there's an actual username.

**Attempt**

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const { nickname, password } = req.body;
    // Create a new object based on email or username
    const login = {};
    if (nickname.indexOf('@') === -1) {
        check('nickname').isLength({ 'min': 3 });
        login.nickname = nickname;
    } else {
        check('nickname').isEmail();
        login.email = nickname;
    }
    login.password = password;
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
});
```

Seemed like the validator just didn't work.

Comment: i got a resolve for this problem on here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60216241/2262856

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
npm install validator
```

and

```
npm install express-validator
```

then

```
const {check, oneOf } = require('express-validator')
const validator = require('validator')
```

in your validation function try this,

```
oneOf([
  check('nickname').isEmail(),
  check('nickname').not().isEmpty().isString().custom((value, {req})=>{
     if(!validator.isEmail(value)){
       req.body.flag = true
       // you can handler your req.body here .... 

     }
     return true
  })
]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`oneOf`](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/check-api.html#oneofvalidationchains-message) to validate either username or email. Here is an example:

```
const util = require('util');
const { validator } = require('express-validator');
const { check, oneOf, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');


const validation = [
    oneOf([
        check('nickname')
          .exists()
          .withMessage('nickname is required')
          .isLength({ min: 3 })
          .withMessage('wrong nickname length'),

        check('nickname')
          .exists()
          .withMessage('nickname is required')
          .isEmail()
          .withMessage('nickname not valid'),
    ]),
    check('password')
        .exists()
        .withMessage('password is required')
];

function handleValidationErrors(req, res, next) {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    console.log(util.inspect(errors.array()));
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  next();
};

router
  .post('/', validation, handleValidationErrors,
    (req, res) => {
      const isEmail = validator.isEmail(req.body.nickname);

      res.status(200).json({ isEmail });
    });
```

`nickname` can be either a string with length more than 3 or an email. Password is always required. The array of validators is passed as an array of middleware to `router.post()`. `handleValidationErrors()` is just a helper function. You can have the same logic in the actual logic, or use try-catch if you want.

I use `isEmail()` inside the main callback to check whether it's a username or email. Then I send that in the response. You can use `isEmail` to however you like.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) validator (`npm install joi --save`)

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const validateRequest = (schema) => async (req, res, next) => {
    const { error } = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);

    if (error) {  
      throw new Error(error);
    }

    return next();
  };

const validationSchema =  Joi.object().keys({
    nickname:  [Joi.string().email(), Joi.string().min(3)],
    password: Joi.string().required(),
  }),

router.post('/', validateRequest(validationSchema), (req, res) => 
// rest of your code
```

But a quick fix for your code would be to pass variable `nickname` to `check` and not string:

```
    check(nickname).isLength({ 'min': 3 });
    check(nickname).isEmail();
```